# How to conditionally remove a field from an array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Listing` collection with the following document:

```
{
  owner: ObjectId('12345678'),
  bids: [
    {
      amount: 36,
      date: 2021-06-23T21:00:00.000+00:00,
      placedBy: ObjectId('1111111')
    },
    {
      amount: 16,
      date: 2021-06-23T21:00:00.000+00:00,
      placedBy: ObjectId('22223332')
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to query the `bids` array, but remove the field `placedBy` (for all elements in the array) **only if** a condition is met.
This is what I have so far:

```
async getBids(listingId: string, user: UserDocument) {
        return this.listingModel.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: Types.ObjectId(listingId) } },
            {
                $project: {
                    'bids.date': 1,
                    'bids.amount': 1,
                    'bids.placedBy': {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {
                                '$eq': ['$owner', Types.ObjectId(user.id)]
                            },
                            then: '$bids.placedBy',
                            else: '$$REMOVE'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
    }
```

This works fine for when the condition is `false` (`bids.placedBy` is removed), but when the condition is met I get this (`bids.placedBy` turns into an array of all `placedBy`s):

```
bids: [
    {
      amount: 36,
      date: 2021-06-23T21:00:00.000+00:00,
      placedBy: [
        ObjectId('1111111'),
        ObjectId('22223332')
      ]
    },
    {
      amount: 16,
      date: 2021-06-23T21:00:00.000+00:00,
      placedBy: [
        ObjectId('1111111'),
        ObjectId('22223332')
      ]
    }
  ]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: just use `then: 1,` instead of `then: '$bids.placedBy',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` to loop over the array and set the condition

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "bids": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$bids",
          "in": {
            amount: "$$this.amount",
            date: "$$this.date",
            placedBy: {
              $cond: [ { "$eq": [ "$owner", 1 ] }, "$$this.placedBy", "$$REMOVE" ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWNEBC3bYOS)**